# REUSE a UITableView with its UI/delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 `UIViewControllers`, the 2 ones are containing EXACTLY the SAME `UITableView`(with its custom cells and delegate methods).
My question is their any way to "centralize" the `UITableView` UI and code(datasource and delegates), so that I just have to modify in one file instead of 2 .

Comment: create a separate object that is the data source and delegate and use it in both?

Comment: Your two UIViewController should have the same father. That is , you need create your MyFatherViewControllers, with all the code of your UITableView, and create the both ViewControllers as son of this: MyFirstViewController:MyFatherViewController. And put here the difference code.

Comment: @Fonix: Yes, but that MyFatherViewController, has a xib file containing the UITableView ? And then, in MyFirstViewController, how can I retrieve that UI and delegate methods ?

Comment: @OnikIV please see above my question .

Comment: I usually don't use xib or storyboard, all by code my proporsal is easy to implement. If you have a xib I recomend use xib files only to the father. (If you need add some other view, add in viewDidLoad), you need to implement initWithNib in the sons in order to charge the father nib, connections with xib only in father, if you need some functionalities from connections in son (override the actions with void works fine). New views use target-actions by code. If you need a bigger explanation let my know an I'will do a answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

following up on my comment, the table view in the xib in your father vc and the delegate methods in your father vc are just in the same place because you chose it to be like that, the table view and the delegate methods are actually quite detached.

so create a new object, say `FatherTableController` which implements `UITableViewDatasource` and `UITabelViewDelegate` and copy those methods out of your `FatherViewController` into this `FatherTableController`

now in your FatherViewController, go like

```
FatherTableController tableController = [FatherTableController new]; //should be a property or a singleton

self.tableview.delegate = tableController;
self.tableview.datasource = tableController;
```

now you can do that in both your separate vc's that use the same table, and even use the exact same table contoller between the two views if you share it in some way (possibly via a singleton pattern, which can be useful for sharing state between the two view controllers)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
@interface FatherViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *parentTableView;

@implementation FatherViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.parentTableView.delegate=self;
        self.parentTableView.dataSource=self;
    }

    //declare the delegate / datasource methods
```

--------------------- CHILD VIEW CONTROLLER ---------------------

```
@interface ViewController : FatherViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
}
```